Programatically check user access to content type edit/create
Is there a way in Drupal 10 to programmatically check to see if the current logged in user can access the edit/create/view for each content type.

Does this answer your question? Check access to entity for logged in user in Drupal 8

Use the the access manager service:
$access_manager = \Drupal::service('access_manager');

To check if the current user can edit a specific node:
$has_access = $access_manager->checkNamedRoute('entity.node.edit_form', ['node' => '1']);

Or can create a node for a specific content type:
$has_access = $access_manager->checkNamedRoute('node.add', ['node_type' => 'article']);


That's perfect, does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

If you have the entity object you can use access method:
$currentUSer =  \Drupal::currentUser();
// Check different access.
$hasEditAccess =  $entity->access('edit', $currentUSer);
$hasViewAccess =  $entity->access('view', $currentUSer);
$hasCreateAccess =  $entity->access('create', $currentUSer);

Otherwise you can create your own access check function that takes entity type and bundle to, something like:
/**
   * Check user access.
   *
   * @param string $operation
   *   The operation eg view|edit|create.
   * @param string $bundle
   *   Bundle.
   * @param string $entity_type_id
   *   Entity type.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface|NULL $account
   *   User account to check access.
   *
   * @return bool
   */
  function checkUserAccess(string $operation = 'view', string $bundle = 'article', string $entity_type_id = 'node', AccountInterface $account = NULL): bool {
    $account = $account ?: \Drupal::currentUser();
    // Check if the user has the permission to apply operation of this type.
    return $account->hasPermission("$operation any $bundle $entity_type_id");
  }

and then you can check with something like:
checkUserAccess('create', 'page','node', account: $this->currentUser());

checkUserAccess() assumes all entity types use permissions in the style of \Drupal\entity\EntityPermissionProvider, it ignores admin permissions, and it ignores custom access alters.
